# Where is the "roll up inputs" icon explained?

Tags: predictive-interface

Searching "roll up" on this site gives me only [How do I convert Mathematica's suggestions to usable code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39680/how-do-i-convert-mathematicas-suggestions-to-usable-code/39682?s=1|0.8828#39682) which mentions the icon but says little about it.

I found nothing on it in the Mathematica documentation.  Clicking a link for "Search all Mathematica sites" gave

> Sorry, but no results matched for '"roll up inputs"'. Please try
>   again.

I even searched the documentation for the phrase "combine several actions into one input expression" which is tied to this icon in one of the tutorials.  But I cannot find a description of the use of the icon.

Where is it described?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes, that page uses the phrase ""combine several actions into one input expression."  But that page does not explain how it works.

Comment: Oh I see. It looks like that's all there is in the documentation. The only other reference I could easily find is in this Wolfram [blog post](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2012/12/what-are-you-going-to-do-next-introducing-the-predictive-interface/) but there's just a brief mention: *"If you want to repeat the sequence of computations here, you typically want to 'roll them up' into a single line—which is what the spiral icon in the Suggestions Bar does"*

Comment: I find the suggestion bar is often useful. I have not had any problems with it such as others have reported. I think the user is expected to learn what it can do by experimenting with it, which I often do. I have been pleasantly surprised by some the things I have learned from these experiments. The roll-up button seems to do something like run `FullDefinition` and then make back substitutions. I have not found it very useful.

Comment: I see no significant reason why this question should be closed. Logically a professional consultant close doesn't follow when good answers have been provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those that don't know, the roll up button in the [suggestion bar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html) is the highlighted button in the following image:

[image]

The roll up button is activated when several suggestion bar actions have been used consecutively. In the following example I am doing some image processing using only the suggestion bar; I start from an image and I apply some transformations that I find in the suggestion bar beneath the previous output.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I have the option to use the "roll up" button to compound all the suggestion bar actions that I've taken into one command. If I use the roll up button on my example above, I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor, and **disable** that suggestions bar *immediately*, and never, ever look at it again. Some extremely serious bugs have been identified in connection with the presence of the suggestions bar (see, e.g., [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124005/mma11-on-windows-forgetful-kernel/124009#124009), and references therein), which causes the frontend to silently mangle your input and produce incorrect results. These issues exist in version 10 and 11 of Mathematica. You have been warned.

So, to answer your actual question: Don't worry about finding information on how to use that icon; you should not use it in the first place.

Comment: Yes I disable the suggestion bar whenever I am really working with Mathematica.  But when I am exploring Mathematica to see what it can do, the suggestions open new avenues to me.  It seems that "rolling up input" is a different issue though.  What does it mean anyway?

Comment: Ah, I may not be using "disable" the way you do.  I go to "preferences" and uncheck the "show suggestions" box.  Do you mean something more extreme than that?

Comment: No, that's what I meant, nothing any more drastic.

Comment: As an aside, whoever down-voted the above answer of mine might want to consider explaining why they did so. Just to be clear, I really don't care about the downvote itself, but I and perhaps others too could learn more if people commented rather than leaving some unexplained downvote.

Comment: @Pirx I didn't downvote, but I might look at this answer and think it doesn't actually answer the question. I don't have an answer either, and I also disable the suggestions bar, but I don't have an answer for "what is the suggestions bar doing here?".

Comment: @Jason B. Yeah, I had the same thought myself, but then I wasn't sure the OP was aware of the dangers so I thought this might be helpful to him and possibly others. In hindsight, putting this in the form of a comment might have been better.